# Is array the pointer to the first element, if yes...?

Tags: c, arrays

...then why is the code below give same value (meatballs) for address and the actual content? And how to make sense of %d value of meatballs, is it random?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int meatballs[5]= {1,2,3,4,5};

    printf("\nmeatsballs %p %p %d \t \n",meatballs, &meatballs, 
          meatballs);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: [Is an array name a pointer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

1. `meatballs` is an array, and it has type `int[5]`. However C doesn't allow passing arrays by value, so array decays into pointer for function call. This is equivalent of pointer to first element of array `&meatballs[0]`, and it has type `int*`.
2. `&meatballs` is a pointer to an array, and it has type `int(*)[5]`. Since it's a pointer it can be passed to a function.

As you can see, both 1. and 2. return same address, but they have different types: pointer to integer array vs pointer to single integer.

**Note:** Types `void*` and `int*` don't necessarily have the same representation<sup>(1)</sup>, and for `%p` only valid type is `void*`<sup>(2)</sup> or you will get *undefined behaviour*<sup>(3)</sup>. Always convert pointer to `void*` when printing addresses:

```
printf("%p %p", (void*)meatballs, (void*)&meatballs);
```

3. Last situation is same as first, but you are using wrong type specifier `%d`. Resulting type is again `int*` as in case 1, but it is interpreted as `int`. This is clear *undefined behaviour*, and output is garbage.

To print integer array element, use any of the following methods:

```
printf("%d %d %d", meatballs[i], *(meatballs + i), *meatballs);
```

First two will print array element at index `i`, and last will print first element. I recommend using the `meatballs[i]` in most cases, as it's most clear.

---

References to C standard (draft):

1. N1570, 6.2.5 paragraph 28

   > A pointer to **void** shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type.<sup>48)</sup>... ...Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements.
2. N1570, 7.21.6 paragraph 8

   > **p**    The argument shall be a pointer to **void**. ...
3. N1570, 7.21.6 paragraph 9

   > ... If any argument is
   >   not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
   >   undefined.

Comment: Technically, there is no need to cast `meatballs` or `&meatballs` to `void*` as both are simply memory addresses which are `void *` to begin with. However, for the purpose of discussion it does no harm.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin No, standard is pretty clear on this. `void*` is only required to have same representation as `char*` (N1570, 6.2.5 p28), and `%p` strictly requires `void*` (7.21.6 p8).

Comment: Unless you are interpreting it differently, that means there is no cast required between the `char *` and `void *` pointers for any purpose to the extent `%p` cares. Are you saying something else that I'm missing? They are compatible types. Specifically, note:48 addresses `void *` and `char *` compatibility: 48) The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as arguments to functions, return values from functions, and members of unions

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I was trying to say that `void*` and `int*` are not interchangeable, and that's why cast is needed on `printf`. But as you say, according to note 48, cast to `char*` should also suffice.

Comment: Nicely structured and complete answer!-) Just for extending the last example: `printf("%d %d", *(meatballs + 1), meatballs[1]);` prints the array's second element (twice). And why not add the Standard reference mentioned in the comment to the answer?

Comment: @alk Thank you. I added you suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the unary dereference operator `*`, so that the actual value is shown as `%d` expects an integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int meatballs[5]= {1,2,3,4,5};

    printf("\nmeatsballs %p %p %d \t \n",meatballs, &meatballs, 
          *meatballs);

    return 0;

}
```

Look at the last parameter: `*meatballs`. This code actually prints `1` as value and is the first element in your array. So your guess is right and it is only a bug.

Comment: thanks for responding, now what about the meatballs and &meatballs having same value, are they allowed to be same if its a pointer.

Comment: @ManishKumarSingh name of array evaluates the addr of the first element in the array, so meatballs and &meatballs has same value. The next element array will not. e.g. meatballs+1 and &meatballs+1 .